# Getting the following error when tried to deploy node js app on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

This is my first time using Google Cloud and I tried to send it. As per the tutorial on YouTube, I have a app.yaml file which looks like this:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
```

When I ran gcloud app deeply, it failed. In the terminal, there was an error, and it told me to go to this page for the full details, and here is what the page gave me:

```
{
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Login Required.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "required",
"location": "Authorization",
"locationType": "header"
}
],
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}
}
```

PS: I am not trying to do any google authentication on my website.

Here is what I got in my terminal, it is a bit messy:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Flex operation projects/turing-problems/regions/us-east1/operations/0cfe7722-014c-4834-b184-00b9e4961379 error [INTERNAL]: An internal error occurred while processing task /appengine-flex-v1/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2020-07-24T16:34:33.630Z4931.jc.12: Deployment Manager operation turing-problems/operation-1595608474469-5ab328c52462a-0c83d4d8-c6c54fdd errors: [code: "RESOURCE_ERROR"
location: "/deployments/aef-default-20200724t123246/resources/aef-default-20200724t123246"
message: "{\"ResourceType\":\"compute.beta.regionAutoscaler\",\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"403\",\"ResourceErrorMessage\":{\"code\":403,\"message\":\"The caller does not have permission\",\"status\":\"PERMISSION_DENIED\",\"statusMessage\":\"Forbidden\",\"requestPath\":\"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/turing-problems/regions/us-east1/autoscalers\",\"httpMethod\":\"POST\"}}"
]
```

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: Yes. I used gcloud auth login to login. It opened in the browser and I logged in. Furthermore, I also got the page stating that I am authenticated

Comment: You are publishing your project to App Engine Flexible and you do not have IAM permission to do so. Read the following link. You are missing one of the Predefined App Engine roles assigned to the account you have authenticated with or the service account assigned to the CLI `gcloud`: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/roles

Comment: The Codelab might help you understand the process: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-vision-app-engine/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0